# PHP How to stop variable from being rewritten when form resubmitted

Tags: php, html, var

I have 2 forms, the first obtains the ID of a person in table of a database. The second gets a name and/or address to update for that ID. I am losing the value of ID when the page is refreshed. Below is how I have declared and posted a value to the id. How can I stop this from being rewritten when the next form is submitted and the page refreshed? (the session_start() is at the top of the document)

```
 $_SESSION['ID'] = $_POST['id'];
 $id = $_SESSION['ID'];
```

Form 1:

```
 <form method="post">
    <p style="margin-top: 70px;">Please type the ID of the person you wish to add to change their data</p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">ID</p>
    <input style="color:black" type="text" name="id" placeholder="10001">
    <input style="color:lightblue;background-color: rgb(80,80,80);margin-top: 7px;" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Form 2:

```
 <form method="post">
    <p>New Information for Customer with ID entered above</p>
    <input style='color:black;' type="text" name="newName" placeholder="New Name">
    <input style="color:black;" type="text" name="newAddress" placeholder="New Address">
    <input style="color:lightblue;background-color: rgb(80,80,80);margin-top: 7px;" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It's not `start_session()`, it's `session_start()`

Comment: I typed it wrong in the description. Sorry, it has been corrected

Comment: Then put some logic in that checks your sending up the value.

Comment: add a hidden input with the id as name/value to your second form: `<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $id; ?>'>`

Comment: [Read this](https://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/3940.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both forms are missing the `action` attribute for the `form` i assume, that both are on the same page. This leads to the problem, that you can only submit one form at a time.
The moment you submit the second form the `$_POST` data will be set to the fields available in that form and therefore `$_POST['id']` is removed. Since you seem to always call `$_SESSION['ID'] = $_POST['id'];` you will rewrite it with `NULL` and therefore delete the entry. You could instead check if the `id` was really submitted:

```
if (array_key_exists('id', $_POST)) {
    $_SESSION['ID'] = $_POST['id'];
}
$id = $_SESSION['ID'];
```

Like this your session will keep the id.

Alternatively, because you do not have any fields in your second form, that need to load data from the specified user, you can also merge the input fields to your first form. Like this, the `id` will always be submitted again and kept, because it is part of the submitted `form`.

```
<form method="post">
    <p style="margin-top: 70px;">Please type the ID of the person you wish to add to change their data</p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">ID</p>
    <input style="color:black" type="text" name="id" placeholder="10001">
    <p>New Information for Customer with ID entered above</p>
    <input style='color:black;' type="text" name="newName" placeholder="New Name">
    <input style="color:black;" type="text" name="newAddress" placeholder="New Address">
    <input style="color:lightblue;background-color: rgb(80,80,80);margin-top: 7px;" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In an addition you should submit the given values back to the user, so the form keeps the fields:

```
<input style="color:black" type="text" name="id" value="<?= $id ?? '' ?>" placeholder="10001">
<input style="color:black;" type="text" value="<?= array_key_exists('newAddress', $_POST) ? $_POST['newAddress'] : '' ?>" name="newAddress" placeholder="New Address">
...
```

Comment: I tried this now my SQL doesn't work and returns an undefined index

Comment: @EnterStrandman Yes, i entered the wrong key in the array_key_exists clause when checking if the id was submitted. I fixed that. Your error should not occur any longer.

Comment: That fixed trhe SQL Error, but I still have the problem of the ID being set back to null when the form is submitted again.